# "az login --allow-no-subscriptions" not supported anymore?

Tags: azure-cli2

According to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/#login

following, should be supported but fails:

az login --allow-no-subscriptions

**ERROR: az: error: unrecognized arguments: --allow-no-subscriptions**

I actually wanted to login into my B2C tenant:

az login --tenant

But this fails with following message:

**ERROR: No subscriptions found for this account.**

How can I login via azure-cli into my B2C tenant directory, in order to navigate through users etc.? I'm on Windows 10, running azure-cli (2.0.3)

Help is appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Actually I was able to find the answer myself. This was a limitation in azure-cli itself, which has already been implemented meanwhile:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/pull/2929

I was able to validate it works with a development docker image.